# Cannot get index of an element

Tags: jquery

I want to get the index of `d-flex` that is inside `#Equipmentsfield_wrapper` but my code does not work. I know that's wrong but I'm using this

```js
alert($('#Equipmentsfield_wrapper').children('div').index());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="Equipmentsfield_wrapper">
  <div class="d-flex">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="equipments[]" value="" required/>
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" id="Equipmentsadd_button" class="fieldAddDeleteIcon" title="Add field"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></a>
  </div>
  <div class="d-flex">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="equipments[]" value="" required/>
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" id="Equipmentsadd_button" class="fieldAddDeleteIcon" title="Add field"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What are you expecting `this` to be a reference to?

Comment: Where is your code? The `$(this)` when refer to element that your code be inside event handler or `.each()` loop

Comment: Oh sorry, its refer to #Equipmentsfield_wrapper

Comment: Ok, in that case your use of `index()` is backwards. You need to select the actual element within the parent that you want to know the index of. At the moment you're selecting them both, and hence calling `index()` only works on the first one, so the response will always be `0`

Comment: *"I want to get the index of d-flex that is inside #Equipmentsfield_wrapper"* There are two of them. Which one's index do you want? When do you want it? (For instance, in response to some kind of event?) The more complete you can make your question, the better.

Answer (score 2):

You are selecting a collection of elements. You can loop over it printing the index. Otherwise you need to narrow down your collection.

```js
$('#Equipmentsfield_wrapper').children('div').each(function(){
  console.log($(this).index());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="Equipmentsfield_wrapper">
  <div class="d-flex">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="equipments[]" value="" required/>
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" id="Equipmentsadd_button" class="fieldAddDeleteIcon" title="Add field"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></a>
  </div>
  <div class="d-flex">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="equipments[]" value="" required/>
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" id="Equipmentsadd_button" class="fieldAddDeleteIcon" title="Add field"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></a>
  </div>
</div>
```